# NGINX not executing PHP files

Tags: php, nginx

I could not find an answer for this. Installed PHP5 + NGINX + PHP-FPM and can not execute php files, it get a "Oops! This link appears to be broken." error in CHROME. I do not have any valuable error log report, i do have a index.php in the root, tried creating a custom phpinfo.php file, neither worked.

I DO can load HTML files, but cant PHP.

Here is my local site config in NGINX:

```
server {
    listen       80;
    server_name  im;
    access_log /var/www/website/access.log;
    error_log /var/www/website/error.log;

    location / {
        root   /var/www/website;
        index  index.html index.htm index.php;
    }


    location ~ \.php$ {
        fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME  /var/www/website$fastcgi_script_name;
        include /etc/nginx/fastcgi_params;
    }

}
```

Changed ownership of all the directory to www-data:www-data, made a 777 on the php file, nothing. Restarted nginx, FPM, nothing.

Help? :(

Comment: look in your error log

Comment: Already did, "I do not have any valuable error log report". It's completely empty.

Comment: You need more data to diagnose the problem. I would suggest starting by adding 'fastcgi_intercept_errors on;' to your config (if not in fastcgi_params) to log any FPM errors. Also add 'debug' to your error_log line to get a lot more detail (also check the main nginx error_log (possibly in /var/log)) . Your server_name directive looks unusual - not sure if you replaced it for this post or it actually is like that. As a general recommendation, move your root directive out of your location block. (Final (unlikely) suggestion: ensure your default server isn't serving the html pages you can see).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> it get a "Oops! This link appears to be broken." error in CHROME.

Chrome shows its own error page if the error page is less than 512 bytes.

I suspect that you have the following line in `fastcgi_params`:

```
fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME  $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
```

and if so, because the `root` directive is defined in `location /` will be never applied to `location ~ \.php$`, thus the `SCRIPT_FILENAME` becomes URI.

This can be solve by moving the `root` directive to the `server` level context:

```
server {
    listen       80;
    server_name  im;
    access_log /var/www/website/access.log;
    error_log /var/www/website/error.log;

    root   /var/www/website;

    location ~ \.php$ {
        fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME  $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        include fastcgi_params;
    }

}
```

Comment: Bingo. Moved root the server block as suggested and worked. Thanks!

Comment: @quanta: Did the OP edit the config in his question? Because it's a hardcoded path it should still work perfectly fine when root directive is defined in location context. The only case where it wouldn't work was if he defined SCRIPT_FILENAME in his fastcgi_params file using $document_root and thus overriden his hardcoded one.

Comment: @MartinF: No, the OP didn't edit the config. You're right. I will edit my answer.

Answer (score -3):

In my case it was missing the php-zip package.  To fix this, I ran:

```
yum install -y php-zip
systemctl restart php-fpm nginx
```

Comment: Apparently, the cause for OP was for something else entirely.

Comment: That doesn't mean that someone who finds their way to this page with this issue will have the same cause as the OP, they may very well have the cause that wejdross did and find this answer useful. The question isn't specific to that cause, it's specific to that symptom, and obviously there's multiple causes for it, so people with different causes could end up here.